# Is there a history of Beer?

Tags: history

I was wondering if there is any definitive history of beer. I know that the ancient Egyptians brewed beer and it has been consumed throughout the centuries but I'd like to know the times and cultures that made it. Also how it was made.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When was the first beer ever brewed?](http://beer.stackexchange.com/questions/2/when-was-the-first-beer-ever-brewed)

Comment: Temporarily putting this question on hold until it's edited to be more answerable. Might be as simple as changing the wording, e.g. "Is there a book or online resource that describes the beer in various cultures throughout history?" Asking whether beer has a "definitive history," in contrast, is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good starting point: [History of beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_beer). I know it's just Wikipedia, but I think it's really well done with many links and external references.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article about beer in the ancient world on beeradvocate.com. I think it's worth reading.

Here's a link: http://www.beeradvocate.com/articles/721/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few. You can definitely start with the wikipedia and BeerAdvocate articles suggested by other posters, but for books, I'd recommend the following.

- Beer: A Global History by Gavin Smith gives a good overview and world perspective.

-A Brewer's Tale: A History of the World According to Beer by William Bostwick focuses more on the effect beer has had on civilization, rather than the other way around

-The Audacity of Hops: The History of America's Craft Beer Revolution by Tom Acitelli is a great prohibition-to-now perspective on American beer.